# vaadin-maven-archetype - Why does it generate three modules?

Tags: maven, vaadin, vaadin7

I used the `vaadin-archetype-application-multimodule` [listed here](https://vaadin.com/maven#archetypes) and discussed on [on this wiki page](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+a+Maven+project).

The archetype generated a project with three sub modules, `myproject-production`  `myproject-ui`  and `myproject-widgetset`. I am not sure the purpose of each project. For example `myproject-production` & `myproject-ui` both are [war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_(Sun)) projects.

I am not sure which parts of my code should go where. Can someone please explain to me the usage of each of the projects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the generated `README.md`:

> - parent project: common metadata and configuration
> - xxx-widgetset: widgetset, custom client side code and dependencies to widget add-ons
> - xxx-ui: main application module, development time
> - xxx-production: module that produces a production mode WAR for deployment

For background: with Vaadin you essentially develop web applications with server-only Java code. This is the "UI" code, which runs on the server and communicates behind the scenes with a kind of "thin client" running in Javascript on the browser (this is the "widgetset"). Normally you don't need to worry but for more advanced things you may create/derive/extend widgetsets. This would go in the Widgetset project.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by geert3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27622590/642706) is correct. I'll add some thoughts.

## Single-module project

First and foremost: **If you are new to Vaadin, do *not* use the multi-module** Maven archetype as your first project (unless you are already a Maven maven).

If new to Vaadin, use the `vaadin-archetype-application` [listed here](https://vaadin.com/maven#archetypes). This single-module produces a working Vaadin app, and indeed is the regular way we worked in Vaadin for many years.

## Multi-module project

The `vaadin-archetype-application-multimodule` archetype produces a project with optimizations for both development and deployment. Use this only after you get the hang of using Vaadin.

### `-parent`

When you first create a Vaadin object, do a “clean and build” in your IDE on the parent module. This in turn executes a build of the other three subordinate modules.

### `-ui`

The `-ui` module is the one you use in your day-to-day Vaadin work. You build your `Layout` objects with widgets and display them in a `UI`. In development, you run/debug your Vaadin app by choosing your IDE’s “run” or “debug” command on this module.

If some of your changes seem to not be taking effect, then do a “clean and build” in your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) on this module. If things seem really out-of-whack, perform a “clean and build” on the `-parent` project.

### `-widgetset`

If you add an [add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory) (plugin/extension) that has a visual component, you will need to do a “clean and build” on the `-widgetset` project. Or do a “clean and build” on the parent.

The “widgetset” comprises the classes and resources used for rendering user-interface widgets such as buttons, fields, labels, and so on.

### `-production`

For deployment, use the `-production` module. It has some optimizations and disables the [Debug Window](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-debug.html) mode as you probably do not want end-users perusing the innards of your Vaadin app.

## Update: Vaadin 8

In Vaadin 8.1, this archetype produces a different set of modules.

- `-parent`
  common metadata and configuration
- `-ui`
  main application module
- `-backend`
  contains any server side java code and dependencies
- `-addon`
  addon module, custom server and client side code

The `ui` module remains the core of your app. Here you find the `MyUI` class extending [`UI`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.1/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html). In turn, that class contains the `MyUIServlet` that extends [`VaadinServlet`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.1/com/vaadin/server/VaadinServlet.html) that implements [`javax.servlet.Servlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html), driving your entire web app.

From the example code created by this archetype, I see they intend the `backend` module to contain classes for accessing data sources such as databases or web services.

Tip: After first creating a project with this archetype, be sure to run the Maven Lifecycle item `install` on the `parent` module. Your project is then fleshed out with additional downloads, fully-configured, and able to run.